# Info and website for Blender snap package is invalid. Where to contact dev?

Tags: snap, blender

I was experiencing a bug for the Blender snap package (site https://uappexplorer.com/app/blender-tpaw.tpaw). But both the github website and email link they provide are inavlid: the email bounces back as "undeliverable".

Question is: how can I contact the dev' on this project? Or where can I go to request that the contact info' be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is where you will find them:-
 https://github.com/TPaw/TPawSnaps